# ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 8 what does it mean?

Tags: vba, excel

what does ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 8 mean in vba?

How does vba know the usedRange?

Comment: It means 8 less columns than are in the UsedRange. It asks Excel :).

Comment: then technically this should work: ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 3 however it makes no difference?

Comment: Makes no difference to what?

Comment: It does not go back 3 row

Comment: So, you want to work with the 3rd row from the end of the UsedRange?

Comment: Using `UsedRange` can be tricky if your data doesn't start in the top-left corner of the worksheet (ie. in A1). Starting with a fresh sheet, enter some data in (eg) E5:E10. `UsedRange.Rows.Count` is 6, but the last row of data is on Row 10.  So, it's not always safe to use the count of `Usedrange.Rows` or `Usedrange.Columns` to identify *where* the data actually is on the sheet.

Comment: Indeed `UsedRange` needs to be used with caution, as it only gives "size" information, rather than "location" information.

Comment: @BernardSaucier - snap! I think I was adding to my comment as you were writing yours.

Comment: @TimWilliams, great minds think alike, I guess :p +1

Answer (score 19):

Here's the exact definition of `UsedRange` ([MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa141370%28v=office.10%29.aspx)) :

> Every Worksheet object has a UsedRange property that returns a Range object representing the area of a worksheet that is being used. The UsedRange property represents the area described by the farthest upper-left and farthest lower-right nonempty cells in a worksheet and includes all cells in between.

So basically, what that line does is :

1. `.UsedRange` -> "Draws" a box around the outer-most cells with content inside.
2. `.Columns` -> Selects the entire columns of those cells
3. `.Count` -> Returns an integer corresponding to how many columns there are (in this selection)
4. `- 8` -> Subtracts 8 from the previous integer.

I assume VBA calculates the UsedRange by finding the non-empty cells with lowest and highest index values.

Most likely, you're getting an error because the number of lines in your range is smaller than 3, and therefore the number returned is negative.

Comment: I have done this but it does not do the minus 3:

Dim LR As Long, LC As Long
    
    LC = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 8
    LR = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 3
    Range("A2", Cells(LR, LC)).copy
    Range("A2").Select

Comment: I suggest you put this code in your question, and make it clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sure, also learn how to debug VBA using the immediate window, debug.print, locals window, etc... It will help you solving a world of problems.

Comment: @KimGysen, a world of problems is an understatement. :p

Comment: + 1 Nicely explained :)  However this `I assume VBA calculates the UsedRange by finding the non-empty cells with lowest and highest index values.` is not entirely true. Excel behaves erratically when it comes to calculating `UsedRange` and hence it is highly unreliable as explained in my post above.

Answer (score 5):

BernardSaucier has already given you an answer. My post is not an answer but an explanation as to why you shouldn't be using `UsedRange`.

`UsedRange` is highly unreliable as shown [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

To find the last column which has data, use `.Find` and then subtract from it.

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        lastCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Column
    Else
        lastCol = 1
    End If
End With

If lastCol > 8 Then
    'Debug.Print ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 8

    'The above becomes

    Debug.Print lastCol - 8
End If
```

Comment: +1....I used `usedRange` in my example cos Bernard did - his fault :) Shame it misbehaves - I've encountered this myself and don't use it - will it, or has it been fixed ?

Comment: @whytheq: My personal opinion? One should forget that there is a word called `usedrange` :P

Comment: I think it is potentially very powerful and could save on a lot of `rows.count).end(xltosomeplace).row.etc.etc` type code ....but it would need to work

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to move around. Try this:

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.select
```

results in....

[image]

If you want to move that selection 3 rows up then try this

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.offset(-3).select
```

does this...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think if you try:

```
Sub Macro3()
a = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 3
End Sub
```

with a watch on `a` you will see it does make a difference.

Comment: Not sure how that's useful to the OP

Answer (score 0):

UsedRange represents not only nonempty cells, but also formatted cells without any value. And that's why you should be very vigilant.