# extend selection to last used column vba

Tags: vba, excel

Code :

```
Sub MyColumnSelect()
Dim myCurrentRow As Long
Dim myLastColumn As Long
myCurrentRow = ActiveCell.Row
myLastColumn = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
Range(ActiveCell, Cells(myCurrentRow, myLastColumn)).Select
End Sub
```

I need to extend my selection from any colum or any row to the last used column in the sheet. This code extends the selection to a particular column, in my case to `column P`. I don't know why is this the case but even if there are only 4 columns, it still extends the selection to `column P`.

Image :
[image]

PS: I know I shouldn't use `select`, but I can't make it work even with `select`. Need Help.

Comment: Use usedrange.columns.count.... Here you can find information to study on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21172108/activesheet-usedrange-columns-count-8-what-does-it-mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ron de Bruin - Find last row, column or last cell](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm) show you how to find the last used column.

```
Sub MyColumnSelect()
    Dim myCurrentRow As Long
    Dim myLastColumn As Long
    myCurrentRow = ActiveCell.Row
    myLastColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1, 1), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column

    Range(ActiveCell, Cells(myCurrentRow, myLastColumn)).Select
End Sub
```

This also works.  But beware that `UsedRange` can sometimes extend past the data do to non-continuous formatting.

> ```
>   Intersect(ActiveCell.EntireRow, ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Select
> ```

### Addendum

As @Rawrplus pointed out using `ActiveCell` and `Selection` are bad habits and should be avoided.  Watch: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&t=3123s&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Comment: Yeah same thing was happening with my code. once I use the code in a data of 4 columns, that last used column will be 4, but when I change the data, still the selection is till 4 columns. Yours worked perfectly. Thankyou so much. I do have one question though, I have same problem in last used row, can U give me answer for that too or should I ask another question. ?

Comment: Read [Ron de Bruin - Find last row, column or last cell](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm).  It's `Select Case 2` in `Function Last(choice As Long, rng As Range)`.

Comment: @TinMan Yuck!!! `ActiveSheet`, `.Select` `On Error Resume next` inside code.. Damn, don't be so cruel and make him learn bad beginner coding habits that he will have to forcefully unlearn. I absolutely would **not** recommend studying from those excerpts!

Comment: @Rawrplus I added a disclaimer.  I hesitated in answering this one but decided to because I have hot keyed similar code before.  Being able to extend the selection like this can be very handy while formatting and editing large worksheets.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of googling would have absolutely yielded an answer. This is the most common way of retrieving the last actively used row

`Shets("Sheetname").Cells(Rows.Count, <inColumn>).End(xlUp).Row`

and column

`Shets("Sheetname").Cells(<inRow>, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

In your case, presuming your sheet is named "`Sheet1`" it would be:

```
Dim lr as Long
Dim lc as Long
lr = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
lc = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Obviously, if your column ranges vary, you should retrieve them in a loop (eg. loop through all the active rows)

```
For i = 3 to lr
   lc = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   ' do something
Next i
```

[Also, do absolutely read up on why you should not use `Select`, `ActiveSheet` and so on..](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/5512705)

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, but still couldn't make it work in my code.

Comment: It does work.. you're just not executing anything I presume. Eg do `Debug print lc` after the lc assignment in for loop or check if your sheet is named "Sheet1". Can't give you a better answer than that with the info you provided in your question

Comment: I meant, I couldn't integrate your solution in my answer to extend selection from activecell to the last used column. Thanks again. I'll try it.

Comment: @Rawrplus: D'accord with not to use `Select` at all. But what else except `ActiveSheet` should be used if the macro shall run in the current active sheet?

Comment: @AxelRichter I do get your point. Though the thing is, in large majority of cases, the programmer will know to which Sheet will the code apply to. I'm not necessarily implying you should never ever use `ActiveSheet`. Actually for that matter, even `Select` could have it's uses - what I am however saying is, that it is a bad habit which can almost always be avoided and should be used when only absolutely necessary (which almost never is)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub MyColumnSelect()

Dim myRow, myLastColumn As Long

 For myRow = 3 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

  myLastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(myRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

  ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(myRow, 1), Cells(myRow, myLastColumn)).Copy

 Next

End Sub
```